# "efibootmgr: Could not set variable Boot0000: No such file or directory" and "efibootmgr: Could not prepare boot variable: No such file or directory"

Tags: boot, uefi, grub-efi, efibootmgr

grub-efi-amd64-signed installing for x86_64-efi platform occasionally (~1 out of 20 tests) fails to create the Boot0000 record with the following errors "efibootmgr: Could not set variable Boot0000: No such file or directory" and "efibootmgr: Could not prepare boot variable: No such file or directory"

I have even attempted to delete all boot records before running `grub-install -v /dev/sda` without success.

I want to get this reliability working using grub over suggested readings to use rEFInd.

[The rEFInd Boot Manager: Keeping rEFInd Booting](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html)

The following sequence is my debug information:

```
+ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
No BootOrder is set; firmware will attempt recovery
Boot0002* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........m.K.I.N.G.S.T.O.N. .S.M.S.2.0.0.S.3.6.0.G....................A.........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.0.5.2.0.B.6.2.7.1.6.3.0.5.B.B.D. . . . ......AMBOAMNO........{.K.i.n.g.s.t.o.n.D.a.t.a.T.r.a.v.e.l.e.r. .3...0.P.M.A.P....................A.......................N..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.K.i.n.g.s.t.o.n.D.a.t.a.T.r.a.v.e.l.e.r. .3...0.P.M.A.P......AMBO
Boot0003* UEFI: KingstonDataTraveler 3.0PMAP    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x7)/USB(2,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x4294967189,0x800,0x1cdf000)AMBO

+ update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-131-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-131-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done

++ seq 0 9
+ for i in '$(seq 0 9)'
+ efibootmgr -b 0000 -B
efibootmgr: Could not delete Boot0000: No such file or directory
efibootmgr: Could not delete boot variable: No such file or directory
+ for i in '$(seq 0 9)'
+ efibootmgr -b 0001 -B
efibootmgr: Could not delete Boot0001: No such file or directory
efibootmgr: Could not delete boot variable: No such file or directory
+ for i in '$(seq 0 9)'
+ efibootmgr -b 0002 -B
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
No BootOrder is set; firmware will attempt recovery
Boot0003* UEFI: KingstonDataTraveler 3.0PMAP
+ for i in '$(seq 0 9)'
+ efibootmgr -b 0003 -B
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
No BootOrder is set; firmware will attempt recovery
+ for i in '$(seq 0 9)'
+ efibootmgr -b 0004 -B
efibootmgr: Could not delete Boot0004: No such file or directory
efibootmgr: Could not delete boot variable: No such file or directory
+ for i in '$(seq 0 9)'
+ efibootmgr -b 0005 -B
efibootmgr: Could not delete Boot0005: No such file or directory
efibootmgr: Could not delete boot variable: No such file or directory
+ for i in '$(seq 0 9)'
+ efibootmgr -b 0006 -B
efibootmgr: Could not delete Boot0006: No such file or directory
efibootmgr: Could not delete boot variable: No such file or directory
+ for i in '$(seq 0 9)'
+ efibootmgr -b 0007 -B
efibootmgr: Could not delete Boot0007: No such file or directory
efibootmgr: Could not delete boot variable: No such file or directory
+ for i in '$(seq 0 9)'
+ efibootmgr -b 0008 -B
efibootmgr: Could not delete Boot0008: No such file or directory
efibootmgr: Could not delete boot variable: No such file or directory
+ for i in '$(seq 0 9)'
+ efibootmgr -b 0009 -B
efibootmgr: Could not delete Boot0009: No such file or directory
efibootmgr: Could not delete boot variable: No such file or directory
+ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
No BootOrder is set; firmware will attempt recovery

+ grub-install -v /dev/sda
grub-install: info: executing modprobe efivars 2>/dev/null.
grub-install: info: Looking for /sys/firmware/efi ...
grub-install: info: ...found.
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: info: cannot open `/boot/grub/device.map': No such file or directory.
grub-install: info: /dev/sda1 is not present.
grub-install: info: Looking for /dev/sda1.
grub-install: info: /dev/sda is a parent of /dev/sda1.
grub-install: info: /dev/sda1 starts from 34.
grub-install: info: opening the device hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: drive = 0.
grub-install: info: the size of hostdisk//dev/sda is 117231408.
grub-install: info: drive = 0.
grub-install: info: the size of hostdisk//dev/sda is 117231408.
grub-install: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sda for LDM.
grub-install: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sda for LDM.
grub-install: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sda for LDM.
grub-install: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sda for LDM.
grub-install: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-install: info: Partition 0 starts from 34.
grub-install: info: /dev/sda1 is present.
grub-install: info: Looking for /dev/sda1.
grub-install: info: /dev/sda is a parent of /dev/sda1.
grub-install: info: /dev/sda1 starts from 34.
grub-install: info: opening the device hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: drive = 0.
grub-install: info: the size of hostdisk//dev/sda is 117231408.
grub-install: info: drive = 0.
grub-install: info: the size of hostdisk//dev/sda is 117231408.
grub-install: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sda for LDM.
grub-install: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sda for LDM.
grub-install: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sda for LDM.
grub-install: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sda for LDM.
grub-install: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-install: info: Partition 0 starts from 34.
grub-install: info: /dev/sda1 is present.
grub-install: info: Looking for /dev/sda1.
grub-install: info: /dev/sda is a parent of /dev/sda1.
grub-install: info: /dev/sda1 starts from 34.
grub-install: info: opening the device hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: drive = 0.
grub-install: info: the size of hostdisk//dev/sda is 117231408.
grub-install: info: drive = 0.
grub-install: info: the size of hostdisk//dev/sda is 117231408.
grub-install: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sda for LDM.
grub-install: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sda for LDM.
grub-install: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sda for LDM.
grub-install: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: scanning hostdisk//dev/sda for LDM.
grub-install: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-install: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-install: info: Partition 0 starts from 34.
grub-install: info: drive = 0.
grub-install: info: the size of hostdisk//dev/sda is 117231408.
...grub-install info continued...
grub-install: info: adding 170 padding fixup entries.
grub-install: info: writing 960 bytes of a fixup block starting at 0xc000.
grub-install: info: reading /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/fshelp.mod.
grub-install: info: reading /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/ext2.mod.
grub-install: info: reading /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/part_gpt.mod.
grub-install: info: reading /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/search_fs_uuid.mod.
grub-install: info: reading /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/load.cfg.
grub-install: info: kernel_img=0xd7cc90, kernel_size=0x18a00.
grub-install: info: the core size is 0x1dbd8.
grub-install: info: writing 0x1ee00 bytes.
grub-install: info: copying `/usr/lib/shim/shimx64.efi.signed' -> `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi'.
grub-install: info: copying `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi-signed/grubx64.efi.signed' -> `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi'.
grub-install: info: copying `/usr/lib/shim/mmx64.efi' -> `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi'.
grub-install: info: copying `/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/load.cfg' -> `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg'.
grub-install: info: Registering with EFI: distributor = `ubuntu', path = `\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi', ESP at hostdisk//dev/sda,gpt1.
grub-install: info: executing efibootmgr --version </dev/null >/dev/null.
grub-install: info: executing modprobe -q efivars.
grub-install: info: executing efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -w -L ubuntu -l \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi.
efibootmgr: Could not set variable Boot0000: No such file or directory
efibootmgr: Could not prepare boot variable: No such file or directory
Installation finished. No error reported.

+ update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-131-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-131-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done

+ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
No BootOrder is set; firmware will attempt recovery
```

I have written a bash script to 100% reproduce this problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
# UEFI NVRAM Variable Reproducibility Unit Test
set -x
while true
do
        efibootmgr -v
        for i in $(seq 0 9)
        do
                efibootmgr -b 000$i -B
        done
        efibootmgr -v
        grub-install
        if [ $(efibootmgr -v | grep -c ubuntu) -eq 0 ]
        then
                echo "BUG!!! OS will now fail to boot!!!"
                exit 0
        fi
done
```

The following is my workaround solution:

```
# ensure fallback UEFI NVRAM boot record variable exists
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -w -L fallback -l '\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi'
```

Creating a second redundant boot record is a perfect workaround for my unreliable hardware problem. This way grub-install can continue to delete, edit and use the Boot0000/ubuntu record. If the Boot0000/ubuntu record is ever lost then the Boot0001/fallback untouched record will be automatically selected by the BIOS and boot the OS.

/var/log/kern.log -> kernel: [ 179.804812] efivars: set_variable() failed: status=8000000000000009

This in combination with the efi_no_storage_paranoia=1 kernel parameter gives me the hardware reliability I need.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI from vendor? What brand/model system.

Comment: How do I exactly update the UEFI from vendor? Product Name KEEX-1650, BIOS Version 1.01, BIOS Build Date 09/12/2013 and Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU D2550 @ 1.86GHz.

Comment: Vendor should have a support page, and then you select your specific model to download new BIOS/UEFI if newer than your 1.01.  That is an earlier model with UEFI, so updates should help. Found this quickly with Google, but limit systems like that also have limited support. http://www.quanmax.com/site/download/

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with my ACER SWITCH3 SW312-31.
I contacted ACER support and received the answer, that the only way to update the EFI (frimware) is to use the installed windows10. I could not find any way with the installed EFI to update the firmware.
Fortunately now I could boot and log in regularly into my (root) account. I am not certain how I maged it.
Before I could not, I updated ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 and on EFI I uploaded the new GRUB / EFI files. Than it happend again, that I could not log in. It seamed that a graphic driver did not work properly. 
The latest action was to disable the EFI secure cheeck and I could log in.
I will check all logging.